# Check if Userform exists

Tags: vba, outlook

There seems to be no userforms when I try to check two ways.

My UserForm is placed here:

[image: Screnshot of Outlook VBA]

The code is placed in Modul3:

```
'Called in Modul3
Sub testUf()
    MsgBox VBA.UserForms.Count            'gives result of 0
    MsgBox isFormLoaded("UserFormNewPath")'gives result of FALSE
End Sub

Function isFormLoaded(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    isFormLoaded = True
    strName = LCase(strName)
    For i = 0 To VBA.UserForms.Count - 1
        If LCase(UserForms(i).Name) = strName Then Exit Function
    Next
    isFormLoaded = False
End Function
```

I want to check if the specified userform exists so I can choose between print details there or in a normal MsgBox.

Why is there no userform counted or what do I have to do to get a TRUE check result?

**Solution**
As warcupine mentioned the following steps helped:

1. Setting the property *ShowModal* of the UserForm to *false*
2. Adding this code line: `UserFormNewPath.Show`

Comment: I tried. But the rest of the code is only executed when I close the UserForm?!

Comment: Perfect, that helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserFormNewPath.Show` to get the UserForm to appear. Then to remove modal, which will stop all executions until you deal with the modal, go to the UserForm Properties and turn modal to False. You can reach properties by right clicking on the form in design mode and there should be a sidebar that appears.

Comment: Actually one more thing: So I only get the information if the UserBox is loaded, not if it exists (and is just not shown yet). Is there a way to get only the existing-information?
Because if I need to show it before I can check it, I will get an error of course...

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean. You can capture the error using an error handler to avoid the error interrupting the execution.